# Слайдер с бесконечной прокруткой

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, слайдер

Как сделать слайдер с бесконечной прокруткой, где при нажатии на правую стрелку, например, первый блок за пределами страницы перемещается в конец и показывается после пятого блока, (т.е. показ. 4,5 и 1-й, а второй и третий исчезают). На экране показываются только три блока, а два за стрелками скрыты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Если нужно сделать именно самому, без подключаемых библиотек, то задублировать содержимое фоток еще раз, и последнюю фотку добавить в начало, чтобы было вот так [5] | [1][2][3][4][5] | [1][2][3][4][5]. Потом, когда доходишь до края слайдера, после прорисовки анимации передвигать незаметно слайдер на дублирующую копию, чтобы по краям всегда было куда листать. Типа того.

Comment: Интересно, кому из модераторов не понравился мой коммент...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). Стилизуется без проблем.

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/rogatnev-nikita/pen/pQMYpv)

```js
jQuery('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>


<div class="slider">
  <div>
    Slide 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Slide 2
  </div>
  <div>
    Slide 3
  </div>
  <div>
    Slide 4
  </div>
  <div>
    Slide 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет, нужен свой велосипед

Comment: Нужен свой велосипед, это как...  Сделать  за тебя?

Comment: Спасибо! Я попробую